# How to modify variables of another scope?

Tags: python, scope

Currectly, I'm trying the following: Some `mutator` function accepts other function's local scope using `locals()`

```
def mutator(locals):
    locals['n'] = 10
    locals['l'].append(10)

def f():
    n = 1
    l = [1]
    mutator(locals())
    print(n,l) # >>> 1, [1,10]

f(None)
```

and that works as expected: I was able to modify mutable list contents but failed to 'rebind' another immutable `int` to the same name.

Currently, I see some options:

- `eval()`, `exec()` & Co
- Play with stack frames & local variables in `mutator()`
- Keep such variables in a `dict`: not very handy but probably the best one

The restriction is: target function `f()` can contain just one function call, possibly with arguments, and that function should be able to alter values in `f()`s current scope.

So.. is there a way to reintroduce variable's value (bind another object) at runtime? I don't believe there is no good trick to achive this!

---

Here's an example of the thing I'm trying to achieve:

```
def view(request): # Yes, that's Django!
    q = MyModel.objects.all()

    data = { 'some_action': True, 'items_per_page': 50 } # defaults. Mutators can change this
    mutators.launch(locals(), data ) # Launch mutators that may want to narrow the QuerySet

    if data['some_action']: # do something useful if no mutator has disabled it
          ...

    # paginate using data['items_per_page']
```

I don't want to use `data` dict here: ability to modify them as local variables would be much better & pretty. Note that `q` QuerySet object is mutable & mutators can alter its contents.

Comment: needs more formatting. indent the method bodies.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's going to be a way of runtime external tuning of function's internal logic, so to say :) Like switching certain booleans on&off to enable/disable features, narrow down some `list` to a subset, etc. I'm sure this is the best way to implement good tuning & extending framework for a highly customizable system.

Comment: It is. If signal-slot architecture is okay — then what's wrong with the idea of signals capable of altering some logic? ;)

Comment: Nothing. But passing in locals() to a random method so that this method can change them can never be the best solution to anything. :-) 
"ability to modify them as local variables would be much better & pretty." No it wouldn't. It's a horrible idea. Luckily it doesn't work.

Comment: @Lennart, ok. Imagine you have a CMS. Every customer wants you to customize it for their needs. Some customizations are reusable (for other sites) as they're successful. Also, we want these customizations to work like source copy-paste BUT it should not incidentally overwrite other customizations. So, we need a way to alter function's behavior, sometimes — even at runtime. My idea is to use 'signals with altering behavior'. Can you suggest a better idea to switch&tune small pieces of code? Re/Defining functions for every primitive action is more horrible :)

Comment: Since that's what I do for a living, I have no problem imagining the situation. "signals with altering behaviour" doesn't say anything. And again, the idea that was bad wasn't "signals with aletring behavior" which still doesn't mean anything, but the idea of modifying locals() by passing it to a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class AttributeCollection(object):
    pass
shared_settings= AttributeCollection()
# now improvise
shared_settings.temperature= 30
shared_settings.samples= []
# etc
```

Pass that `shared_settings` around, or make it global, and set its attributes to whatever you desire.

You see, the `locals()` of a function are just a namespace meant (and optimised for it) to be manipulated inside that function (and while that function is running). Use another namespace (in my suggestion, the `shared_settings` object) as a common playground for your code.

Comment: +1 for encapsulating everything in a class. Thinking about sending your local variables in a blob to somebody else makes me twitchy.

Comment: Just one thing: is there a reason to instantiate a class instead of just using `dict`? We're going to use its `__dict__` attribute only anyway

Comment: @o_O: instantiating a class allows you to use the dot notation for attribute access; if you're going to use a getitem notation, by all means: use a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
def mutator(l):
    l.append(10)
    return 10

def f():
    n = 1
    l = [1]
    n = mutator(l)
    print(n,l) # >>> 1, [1,10]

f()
```

Yeah, I know it isn't the clever hack you want; but it works. :-)

If you want a set of global configuration options that you can turn on and tune, stick all of them on an object:

```
class Settings(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.n = 1
         self.l = [1]
```

Now you can change the variables to your hearts content.

Comment: :))) nice! But that won't look nice when I need to return multiple values. IMHO it's better to use a single dict: `self.n` will use `self.__dict__` anyway

Comment: ... And why would you need to return multiple values? They're all bound together in the Settings! :)